# Need Help Rounding Numbers (Float)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, floating-point, rounding

In the following code, I want the the number that satisfies `if (isKgs)` to be rounded to one decimal point.

For example right now it is giving me `2.2643534543` but I just want `2.3`.

Any ideas?

```
NSNumber *weightInPounds = [self.pickerArray objectAtIndex:row];
NSNumber *weightInKilos = [[DDUnitConverter massUnitConverter] convertNumber: weightInPounds fromUnit: DDMassUnitUSPounds toUnit: DDMassUnitKilograms]; 
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ kgs", [weightInKilos stringValue]];
[self.firstComponentText setString:temp];
```

The the type of number from the picker is `float`, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the `NSNumber` object using an `NSNumberFormatter` object. An example,

```
NSNumber * decimal = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.2643534543];

NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp]; 
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:decimal]);
```

Comment: @Faisal Did this help? Do you need further assistance on this?